# How to download binary file

Tags: flutter

I want to download a binary file which is PDF and save it into my device. The file comes from API response. My `response.body` is like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
void downloadFile() async {
  String url = Uri.encodeFull('https://API_URL');
  http.Response response = await http.post(url, headers: {"Accept": "application/json", HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer '},});
  print(response.body);
}
```

How can I use `response.body` to download the PDF file?

Comment: If you have the response, you already downloaded the data. I guess you just need to write it to a file instead of printing it?

Comment: thank you for your reply, Can I know how to write it to a file?

Comment: `response.bodyBytes` is the binary data. `body` is the same data already passed through a character recorder. The default is Latin 1 unless the content type header included an encoding parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `response.bodyBytes`:

```
void downloadFile(File f) async {
  var url = Uri.encodeFull('https://API_URL');
  var response = await http.post(url, headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer '},});
  await f.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
}
```

I removed the `Accept` header as it made no sense. You're hinting the server that you'll expect JSON, whereas you really want a PDF.

Comment: Is it write like this can download the pdf and save into my phone storage?

Comment: yes - create the path of the file using `path_provider`

Comment: I want to store my file into /storage/emulated/0/Download. How to store it? I use getExternalStorageDirectory but it store in  /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myApps/files

Comment: I add save path code into my code, but now have error about  Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'Instance of 
'Future<Directory>'/file.pdf' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Comment: you need to `await` the `get...Directory` call

Comment: That code couldn't produce `Instance of 'Future...`

Comment: It seems like the problem of how to save binary data to a file is solved. @qing If there is a new problem please ask a new question instead of changing the code in your original question, which makes this answer invalid.

Comment: If this question is now about *where* to store the file you should accept this answer and create a new question about how to use `path_provider` etc

Answer (score 0):

if you using Dio then you can use the below code.

```
await dio.post(finalUrl,
  options: Options(
      responseType: ResponseType.bytes,
      headers: headers,),
  data: encodedBody,);
```