# Invalid characters while converting API response to PDF

Tags: api, flutter, dart, pdf-generation

I used the following syntax for my **GET** request

```
var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    'Accept': 'application/pdf',
}
```

I am **expecting a PDF in response** ,but this is what I got -

```
 %PDF-1.7
 
  1 0 obj
  <<
    /Type /Catalog
    /Pages 2 0 R
  >>
  endobj
 
  2 0 obj
  <<
    /Type /Pages
    /MediaBox [ 0 0 595.00 842.00 ]
    /Count 1
    /Kids [  5 0 R  ]
  >>
  endobj
```

I tried converting the response of API by decoding it using **BASE64** as follows -

`base64.decode(response.body)`

But got *invalid characters* as output.What should I do?

I tried `response.bodyBytes` it returned me some byte array, now how should Ii convert it to PDF/Image?

An update : [This](https://github.com/cowinapi/developer.cowin/issues/47) is an official issue page of that API , and people are getting back a `blob format`. Am I using the API in a wrong way?

Comment: That response looks just like a PDF. Were you expecting something else? It's definitely not Base64.

Comment: How do I convert that response to a viewable PDF. It looks like a post script response to me @Richard. How to do it in Flutter?

Comment: @RichardHeap others are getting `blob format`. But I believe I am getting PostScript which in now way can be converted to PDF. Check this-> https://github.com/cowinapi/developer.cowin/issues/47 is what they did in other languages. But how do we exactly do it in Flutter.

Comment: What you got is exactly how pdfs look internally. Have you tried simply saving those body bytes to a file and opening that file in a pdf viewer?

Comment: Yes I tried saving those bytes @mkl but when I opened the file the text in it was the same postscript , it was not converted to pdf. Maybe I guess I didn't write it the correct way. Those body bytes when read using pdf_viewer, again gives back the post script.

Comment: I am not understanding how to convert response back to a viewable pdf. When I write the bodybytes to a pdf , it gives me back again the same postscript. @mkl

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/pdf_viewer_plugin I used the exact same method mentioned here. Kindly check the code mentioned in the example. I am using the same to write response as bytes to a file and then reading it

Comment: Have you saved it with a `something.pdf` file name?

Comment: Yes @mkl. How should I download it ? I believe in my pdf the content cant be read so that's why I am getting no output. Should I download it? How to do it?

Comment: I don't know the flutter/dart tech stack, so i cannot tell what exactly you have to do. What is clear, though, is that the `%PDF-1.7...` bytes *are* a pdf (or at least a starting piece of one), simply open an arbitrary pdf in a text viewer and compare!

Comment: If you want to display it, you need to download it to a temporary file and then point the pdf viewer at that. For example... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60542879/how-to-download-binary-file/60547280#60547280

Answer (score 0):

You need a response in byteCode or you can say in Unit8List,

So if you use http for API calls then whatever response you get returns it In bytecode like the below code.

`response.bodyBytes`.

or if you using Dio then you can use the below code.

```
await dio.post(finalUrl,
      options: Options(
          responseType: ResponseType.bytes,
          headers: headers,),
      data: encodedBody,);
```