# Flutter http.dart get request to Infura Ipfs API does not download the files in the output directory

Tags: flutter, api, download, xmlhttprequest, ipfs

I have to download the files from ipfs inside a temporary Directory and load that files from that.
I'm using this one: https://docs.infura.io/infura/networks/ipfs/http-api-methods/get

and i referred to the param: output [Optional] - The path where the output should be stored.

```
Future<int> downloadItemIPFS(String hash,String localFolder) async {
  String username = FlutterConfig.get('INFURA_PROJECT_ID');
  String password = FlutterConfig.get('INFURA_API_SECRET');
  String basicAuth = 'Basic ${base64.encode(utf8.encode("$username:$password"))}';
  String tmpPath = await temporaryDirectoryPath;
  Directory dir = await Directory("$tmpPath/$localFolder").create();
  var url = Uri.https('ipfs.infura.io:5001','/api/v0/get',{'arg':hash ,'output': dir.path});
  var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", url);
  request.headers['Authorization'] = basicAuth;
  var response = await request.send();
  var result = await http.Response.fromStream(response);
  return result.statusCode;
}

Future<List<FileSystemEntity>> getDownloadedFiles(String folder) async {
  String tmpPath = await temporaryDirectoryPath;
  Directory dir = Directory("$tmpPath/$folder");
  List<FileSystemEntity> out = dir.listSync();
  return out;
}
```

the response returns 200 but the dyrectory seems empty

**Edited code**

```
Future<int> downloadItemIPFS(String hash,String localFolder) async {
  String username = FlutterConfig.get('INFURA_PROJECT_ID');
  String password = FlutterConfig.get('INFURA_API_SECRET');
  String basicAuth = 'Basic ${base64.encode(utf8.encode("$username:$password"))}';
  String tmpPath = await temporaryDirectoryPath;
  Directory('$tmpPath/$localFolder').create();
  var list = List<int>.generate(100, (i) => i)..shuffle();
  List<int> names = list.take(5).toList();
  String name = '';
  for (int i = 0; i<names.length; i++) {
    name += names[i].toString();
  }
  print("generated file named: $name");
  var url = Uri.https('ipfs.infura.io:5001','/api/v0/get',{'arg':hash,'output': '$tmpPath/$localFolder'});
  Response response = await http.post(url, headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: basicAuth},);
  print("Body content: ${response.body}");
  await File("$tmpPath/$localFolder/$name.txt").writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
  return response.statusCode;
}

Future<List<FileSystemEntity>> getDownloadedFiles(String folder) async {
  String tmpPath = await temporaryDirectoryPath;
  Directory dir = Directory("$tmpPath/$folder/");
  final List<FileSystemEntity> out = await dir.list().toList();
  print("sono dentro getDownloadedFiles in helpefunctions.dart OUT: ${out.length}");
  return out;
}
```

[response format img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GhGB.png)

Comment: Nowhere do you take the `result` and write it to a file. You simply return the status code. Incidentally, you don't actually seem to need a multipart request - it looks like a simple `http.post()` would suffice.

Comment: @RichardHeap ok then I guess I don't understand what the output parameter is for... shouldn't it download it directly to the indicated path? would you have a usage snippet?

Comment: The `output` parameter is sent to the server, which probably sends it back in content disposition header as a hint to a browser to store it. Naturally, that's meaningless (unless *you* parse it out). Just save the `bodyBytes` to your file. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60542879/how-to-download-binary-file

Comment: @RichardHeap thank you very much you have helped me a lot so far.
but now the response only returns the hash without the contents of the file. i have edited adding the new code

Comment: well in that case, continue to send the `output` parameter

Comment: ok maybe the problem is due to the format of the response (i have attached an img in the question). even if the documentation repot that the response is text/plain

Comment: on Postman i receive the full content:
QmdhNwzr6LSxzBNpMTFv7MK1rc5JovhBWPydFa4YCEX3Ws0000644000000000000000000000002414346341142017173 0ustar00000000000000001670930643847/111.56
using Preview
but locally I receive only QmdhNwzr6LSxzBNpMTFv7MK1rc5JovhBWPydFa4YCEX3Ws

@RichardHeap have any ideas?

Comment: `print` will truncate the line, so you are probably getting the whole content. Print `response.bodyBytes.length` to confirm. Fun! You're getting a TAR file. Do you know how to unpack one of those?