# Flutter IPFS infura API get request receive only Hash and not full content from txt file

Tags: flutter, api, ipfs

as a reference of [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74788683/flutter-http-dart-get-request-to-infura-ipfs-api-does-not-download-the-files-in?noredirect=1#comment132006122_74788683), i'm tryng to get a txt file uploded on ipfs with the following request:

```
Future<int> downloadItemIPFS(String hash,String localFolder) async {
  String username = FlutterConfig.get('INFURA_PROJECT_ID');
  String password = FlutterConfig.get('INFURA_API_SECRET');
  String basicAuth = 'Basic ${base64.encode(utf8.encode("$username:$password"))}';
  String tmpPath = await temporaryDirectoryPath;
  Directory('$tmpPath/$localFolder/').create();
  var list = List<int>.generate(100, (i) => i)..shuffle();
  List<int> names = list.take(5).toList();
  String name = '';
  for (int i = 0; i<names.length; i++) {
    name += names[i].toString();
  }
  //var url = Uri.https('ipfs.infura.io:5001','/api/v0/get',{'arg':hash,'output': '$tmpPath/$localFolder/'});
  //http.Response response = await http.post(url, headers: {'Content-Type': "text/plain",HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: basicAuth},);

  var url = Uri.https('ipfs.infura.io:5001','/api/v0/get',{'arg':hash ,'output': '$tmpPath/$localFolder/'});
  var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", url);
  request.headers['Authorization'] = basicAuth;
  StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
  var result = await http.Response.fromStream(response);
  File file = await File("$tmpPath/$localFolder/$name.txt").writeAsString(result.body);
  print("Body content: ${ await file.readAsString()}");
  return response.statusCode;
}

Future<List<FileSystemEntity>> getDownloadedFiles(String folder) async {
  String tmpPath = await temporaryDirectoryPath;
  Directory dir = Directory("$tmpPath/$folder/");
  final List<FileSystemEntity> out = await dir.list().toList();
  return out;
}
```

I receive only the file's hash from the body's response

I tryed to make the same request on postman and I receive the following responses:

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JutKF.png)

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ez0Px.png)

Comment: It's not clear why you are getting a TAR file as the response. You don't appear to be setting `archive=true` (and the default is false if you believe the API doc). Perhaps setting the `output` param flips archive to true. Have you got the simplest case (no optional params) working in Postman?

Comment: @RichardHeap yes i tried both ways (whit and whitout optionals param) and the result was the same

Comment: you got it! I dont know why but all these parameters are ignored even if they are setting to false

Comment: One other thing I notice is that you are doing a POST (which looks correct from the documentation) but adding the parameters (e.g. arg) to the URL. With a POST it's more correct to add them to the body form-encoded. `http.post` will do this for you if you supply them as a map to the `body` parameter of `post`.